# pressure-sensitive, drawable path implementation

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there a pressure-sensitive, alternative `Path` implementation for drawing on a `Canvas`?

I want to be able to declare the ***stroke width*** or ***opacity*** of each point based on a `MotionEvent`.

For now, I just want to append straight line segments. However, the pressure-based parameter should be interpolated between the end points of each line segment.

If there is no ready-to-use solution, of course I appreciate any advices leading to a (performance optimized) self-implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I have chosen, can be described as followed:

- Use multiple paths overlying
- Each path contains only the line segments that are below a certain pressure threshold
- The paths are drawn with alpha value transparency

Disadvantages / potential optimizations:

- The alpha value is not been interpolated along the line segment; therefor the steps of the threshold values ​​are visible.
- Non-transparent lines resulting from high pressure values now produce the most overlying lines, however, could also be represented by a single one
- I wonder whether it is faster

  - to draw the whole paths on invalidation or
  - store the result in a bitmap and only add the new ones

What do you think of my approach? Any suggestions or comments?